# when using typeorm i dont know how to write a query statement

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, typeorm

When the current DB column contains id, category, and price,

The Problem:
Get all values in DB
In case of a specific category ( ex. category === 'food')
How do I write a typeorm query that needs to fetch a value with price greater than 1000?

** Not only receiving specific categories,
It receives all data, but gives conditions to only a specific category.

Comment: I suggest you checking the official documentation of typeorm: https://typeorm.io/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.